# Adding geography to tmap World data frame

Tags: r, tmap

I need to map data of South America and the Caribbean, including small geographies such as St. Vincent and the Grenadines.  However, in the World data set with the `tmap` library these are not included.  Using the included spatial data base of the `tmap` library seems easier than finding, loading, parsing and cleaning a different shape file from some other sources.  Is it possible to insert these countries or should I just fight through learning the details of GIS just to draw a simple thematic map of the Caribbean?

I have battled with reading shape files from OSM today and other mapping packages.  Tmap is a great approach for us non-GIS professionals.

Thanks for any direction you can give.

Comment: You might want to look at [gadm.org](https://gadm.org/) for shapefiles of specific countries (St. Vincent and the Grenadines is included).

Comment: Furthermore: [Please read the info on which question are considered on topic at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Tool/tutorial request like this are considered off-topic.